# Azure Resource Manager: unable to attach existing VHD when creating VM from powershell / azure preview portal

Tags: azure

trying to migrate VMs from Azure Service Management to Azure Resource Manager, after having created new storage accounts and new vm configuration under ARM, I'm not able to deploy VMs WITH attached data disks based on migrated vhds..

Note: the deployment works w/o datadisks, fails with datadisks attached

```html
ResourceGroupName        : 
Id                       : 
Name                     : n1n3-dc-1506
Type                     : 
Location                 : 
Tags                     : null
AvailabilitySetReference : null
Extensions               : null
HardwareProfile          : {
                             "VirtualMachineSize": "Standard_A2"
                           }
InstanceView             : null
NetworkProfile           : {
                             "NetworkInterfaces": [
                               {
                                 "Primary": true,
                                 "ReferenceUri": "/subscriptions/b540a9de-cd22-4d3e-b302-fd57b053cc8e/resourceGroups/N1N3/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/n1n3-dc-1506-NIC0"
                               }
                             ]
                           }
OSProfile                : null
Plan                     : null
ProvisioningState        : 
StorageProfile           : {
                             "DataDisks": [
                               {
                                 "DiskSizeGB": 1000,
                                 "Lun": 0,
                                 "Caching": "ReadOnly",
                                 "CreateOption": "attach",
                                 "Name": "n1n3-dc-1506-data0.vhd",
                                 "SourceImage": null,
                                 "VirtualHardDisk": {
                                   "Uri": "https://n1n3dcstdlrs1506.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/n1n3-dc-1506-data0.vhd"
                                 }
                               }
                             ],
                             "ImageReference": null,
                             "OSDisk": {
                               "OperatingSystemType": "Windows",
                               "Caching": "ReadOnly",
                               "CreateOption": "attach",
                               "Name": "n1n3-dc-1506-os.vhd",
                               "SourceImage": null,
                               "VirtualHardDisk": {
                                 "Uri": "https://n1n3dcstdlrs1506.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/n1n3-dc-1506-os.vhd"
                               }
                             },
                             "SourceImage": null
                           }
```

Deployment status

```html
EndTime             : 19/06/2015 12:12:08 +02:00
Error               : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ApiError
Output              : 
StartTime           : 19/06/2015 12:12:07 +02:00
Status              : Failed
TrackingOperationId : f00aba57-e49d-4574-813a-2dc4803e6aa8
RequestId           : 8fbfc336-05e4-47c4-a211-e2a9a5b40871
StatusCode          : OK
```

Note: deploying the VMs, and trying to attach disks later fails anyway.

```html
# Get the VM
$DC2vm = Get-AzureVM -ResourceGroupName $destResourceGroup -Name $DCvmName
# Add Data Disk 
Add-AzureVMDataDisk –VM $DC2vm –Name $($DCdstVMName + '-data0.vhd') –VhdUri $('https://'+$DCdestSTDStorageName+'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/'+$($DCdstVMName + '-data0.vhd')) –LUN 0 –Caching ReadOnly –DiskSizeinGB 500 -CreateOption attach -Verbose
# Update VM state
Update-AzureVM -ResourceGroupName $destResourceGroup -Name $DCvmName –VM $DC2vm


Update-AzureVM : PropertyChangeNotAllowed: Changing property 'dataDisks' is not allowed.
In riga:4 car:1
+ Update-AzureVM -ResourceGroupName $destResourceGroup -Name $DCvmName –VM $DC2vm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.UpdateAzureVMCommand
```

Any guess?
Many thanks,
Francesco

Comment: This is a relevant ARM template that may be able to help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-multiple-data-disk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, when I used PowerShell script to attach the data disk during the New-AzureVM. My issue was that the DATAdisk had the same uri as the OSdisk, because I used the same variable accidentally.

You can use Azure Resource explorer to check it:
https://resources.azure.com

Select the VM under your subscription/resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ 
and look under StorageProfile.