# Add existing vhd to Azure VM using PowerShell Azure Resource Manager cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

NOTE: This is an Azure ARM question - not an Azure Service Management question.

I have 2 vhds in a storage account - machine-os.vhd and machine-data.vhd. I can use PowerShell ARM cmdlets to create a VM with the existing OS vhd, but cannot figure out how to attach the EXISTING data vhd. All the samples I have found create EMPTY data disks - but I want to attach the existing vhd as a data disk.

I've tried to use the `createOption attach` switch with `Add-AzureVMDataDisk` like so:

`$vm = New-AzureVMConfig ...
$vm = Add-AzureVMDataDisk -VM $vm -VhdUri $existingDiskUri -Name "machine-data.vhd" -Caching ReadOnly -CreateOption attach -DiskSizeInGB 200`

However, the operation fails with:

`Blob https://x.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/machine-data.vhd already exists. Please provide a different blob URI to create a new blank data disk 'machine-data.vhd.'`

I have to specify `DiskSizeInGB` for the `Add-AzureVMDataDisk` command to work (which seems strange). I've tried specifying `SourceImageUri` and a different name for the `VhdUri`, which, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163513.aspx), should copy the vhd from the sourceImageUri to the vhdUri and attach it. Trying `createOption fromImage` fails because "you cannot specify size with source image uri". However, the size parameter for the cmdlet is mandatory, so I don't know how you could specify an sourceUri and not a size.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936060/azure-resource-manager-unable-to-attach-existing-vhd-when-creating-vm-from-powe) presents a similar issue (though I don't get the same error), but the link in the answer shows a template with EMPTY data disks, which doesn't help.

Interestingly I've tried to add the disk to the VM from the Azure Portal - there you have to specify a name and a URI, but the operation always fails with some strange json parsing error. I can't seem to get the uri for the data disk correct.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit more I found a hack:

1. Give a new URI for the existing disk and set this as the `vhdUri`
2. Use the URI of the existing disk as the `sourceImageUri`
3. Call `Add-AzureVMDataDisk` using the `CreateOption fromImage`
4. Set the size of the data disk to null *(this is the hack)*
5. When calling `New-AzureVM`, the existing disk is copied to the new Uri
6. After creating the VM, I delete the original vhd

Unfortunately you have to supply the `DiskSizeInGB` parameter to the `Add-AzureVMDataDisk` command since it's mandatory. However, I set it to null, otherwise the provisioning fails (the error message says that you can't specify both size and sourceImageUri).

Here's the final code:

```
$vm = New-AzureVMConfig ...
$vm = Add-AzureVMDataDisk -VM $vm `
      -SourceImageUri $existingDataDiskUrl -VhdUri $newDataDiskUri `
      -Name $newDataDiskName -CreateOption fromImage -Caching ReadOnly `
      -DiskSizeInGB 200

# hack
$vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks[0].DiskSizeGB = $null
```

After that you can call:
    New-AzureVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm

Once the VM is created, I call `Remove-AzureStorageBlob` to delete the original disk.

Perhaps there's a cleaner way, but I can't find one. At least this way works in the end.